# Can't install ESlint and Prittier dependencies?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, console, eslint

I have a  a package.json file, created one with npm init.
But I failed to install everything needed by the config:
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-wesbos. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.
[image: npm ERR! code 1, command file]

Comment: This is an error caused by `install-peerdeps` when used on Windows. See [this](https://github.com/nathanhleung/install-peerdeps/pull/126#issuecomment-769924227) for more details.